# Error Writing /etc/networking/interfaces/ : No SUch file or directory

Tags: voip, asterisk

I want to setup a VOIP Call using 2 phones, using Asterisk server running on Ubuntu 18.04 on VMWare in Windows 10.

I'm trying to set up a static local IP address for my Linux computer for same network as Win 10. As per every single guide that exists on this subject, I've edited my /etc/network/interfaces
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

## The loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.5
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

It didn't works.

What should i do?

Best Regards,
YH

Comment: Are both phones on the same 192.168.1.* network?

Comment: Welcome! In the body of your question you don't explain the *title* of of it. Can you be more precise on what the error is, when does it appear, and what you have done before.

Comment: No, i just want to start to connect with windows network so after that my plan to configure the asterisk server

Answer (score 0):

My plan is :
1. Setup a wifi on windows 10
2. change NAT with Static IP Ubuntu 18.04 on Win10 host => It didn't worked
3  Configure the asterisk server (sip.conf and extension.conf)